# How to prevent browser back button navigation in nextjs 13 with app based routing?

Tags: browser, navigation, router, next.js13

I got a code for preventing browser backbutton click but when I tried to implement it , I got end up with thte followin error

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

```
import { useRouter} from 'next/router'

const routObj   = useRouter(); // This line cause error

useEffect(() => {
    routObj.beforePopState(({ as }) => {
        if (as !== routObj.asPath) {
            if(showPreview) return false;
            else return true;
        }
        return true;
    });

    return () => {
        routObj.beforePopState(() => true);
    };
    
}, [routObj]);
```

If i use import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";  , routObj.beforePopState is not defined

Is there any alternative method to prevent browser back button click , Any help would be much appreciated